# Is there a difference between modelling variable limits as bounds or constraints?

Tags: pyomo

What is the difference between specifying bounds in `Var(..., bounds=())` versus creating explicit constraints from the solver perspective? Original documentation doesn't say anything about it.

Here is simple model with 2 variables each with 2 timesteps (objective omitted for simplicity). For `x` the limits are defined as a bound. For `y` same limits are defined as constraint.

```py
import pyomo.core as pyo
MAX_VALUE = 10

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.time = pyo.Set(initialize=range(2))
model.x = pyo.Var(model.time, bounds=(0, MAX_VALUE), domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

model.y = pyo.Var(model.time, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.y_max_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.time, rule=lambda model, t: model.y[t] <= MAX_VALUE)

model.pprint()
```

Result is:

```
1 Set Declarations
    time : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}

2 Var Declarations
    x : Size=2, Index=time
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :  None :    10 : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          1 :     0 :  None :    10 : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
    y : Size=2, Index=time
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          1 :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Constraint Declarations
    y_max_constraint : Size=2, Index=time, Active=True
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper : Active
          0 :  -Inf : y[0] :  10.0 :   True
          1 :  -Inf : y[1] :  10.0 :   True

4 Declarations: time x y y_max_constraint
```

Is the approach with limits as constraints more work to solve for the LP solver especially at larger scale, think `time` set in hundreds and dozens of variables? Will there be any post processing that converts all bounds into constraints, or vice versa? Does it matter how i define my limits in pyomo and why? References would be of great help if they exist and i missed them. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, It is exactly the same from the solver's perspective, so either methodology is fine.